# What are the best practices for implementing the == operator for a class in C#?

Tags: c#, operators, equals-operator

While implementing an `==` operator, I have the feeling that I am missing some essential points.
Hence, I am searching some best practices around that.
Here are some related questions I am thinking about:

- How to cleanly handle the reference comparison?
- Should it be implemented through a `IEquatable<T>`-like interface? Or overriding  `object.Equals`?
- And what about the `!=` operator?

(this list might not be exhaustive).

Comment: Check these threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962960/equals-method-implementation-helpers-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421289/icomparable-and-equals, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660566/override-equals-and-gethashcode-question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567642/how-to-best-implement-equals-for-custom-types

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would follow Microsoft's [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/equality-operators).

**edit**: Microsoft's guidelines contain this important remark, which seems to confirm Henk's answer:

> By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by
>   determining if two references indicate the same object, so reference
>   types do not need to implement operator == in order to gain this
>   functionality. When a type is immutable, meaning the data contained in
>   the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator == to compare
>   value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as
>   immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they
>   have the same value. Overriding operator == in non-immutable types is
>   not recommended

Comment: Link is dead in 2018. (This is why we should quote relevant parts of the docs in addition to linking.)

Comment: @rianjs isn't that exactly what I did?

Comment: "What are the best practices for implementing the `==` operator?" followed by "I would follow microsoft's guidelines <with dead link>" quoting a single line from what was once undoubtedly a whole page ("avoid doing it in mutable types") isn't a particularly good answer, no. It isn't complete; it's half a thought which isn't helpful to someone who wants to know the complete set of best practices around implementing a `==` operator.

Comment: Quote expanded to the full paragraph it was taken from.

Answer (score 6):

Each time you implement the `==` operator, be sure to also implement `!=`, `IEquatable<T>` and to override `Object.Equals()` and `Object.GetHashCode()` for consistency for the user of your class.

Considering a class, here's my usual implementation:

```
    public bool Equals(MyClass other) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, this))
            return true;
        return // your equality code here
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        return Equals(obj as MyClass);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return // your hash function here
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyClass left, MyClass right) {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyClass left, MyClass right) {
        return !(left == right);
    }
```

Comment: This. As well, if you implement a < (less than) operator initially, you can use that operator alone to implement every single other operator. ie: == can be expressed as !(left < right || right < left) if the < operator is already implemented.

Answer (score 4):

- If you implement ==, override .Equals and . GetHashCode
- implement != as well
- Check for null references using object.ReferenceEquals otherwise the operator will recurse

Comment: Actually, you HAVE to implement != as well, otherwise C# won't let you compile.

Answer (score 3):

The most common approach is **not** to handle it. The default is reference comparison which in general is right for class objects.

So first you want to be very sure you need value-type behaviour.

Comment: Let there be clear answer of question rather then advice of telling someone to change the way they do things.